# Getting table data as array of rows C# entityframework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My database table 'Table1'  has columns 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'.

I can get `IEnumerable<Table1>` using basic entity framework code.

But, I want my data sent to application layer to be in following format..

```
var data = [[ 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'],
[Column1-Row1-Value,Column2-Row1-Value, Column3-Row1-Value],
[Column1-Row2-Value,Column2-Row2-Value, Column3-Row2-Value],
[Column1-Row3-Value,Column2-Row3-Value, Column3-Row3-Value]]
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Scott the datatype of var is JArray

Answer (score 0):

The easist way to do it is just write a function that take in a `IEnumerable<T>` and outputs the data you want.

```
public void Example()
{
    var myEfModel = GetEFData();
    object[][] result = ConvertToArrayFormat(myEfModel, row => new object[] {row.Column1, row.Column2, row.Column3}, new object[] {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"});
}

public object[][] ConvertToArrayFormat<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataSource, Func<T, object[]> rowSelector, object[] header = null)
{
    var result = new List<object[]>();
    if(header != null)
        result.Add(header);

    foreach (var item in dataSource)
    {
        var row = rowSelector(item);
        result.Add(row);
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Tx, Is it viable to not hard code the column names, also if I wish to convert the result object to JArray, what do I do?

Comment: I found a way to convert to JArray: JArray a = (JArray)JToken.FromObject(result);